# CSS Design query

Tags: html, css

I was doing something with CSS and i got confused with my own code. What i wanted to do was successful but i had a query.

When i change the background color of `#nav` to something it doesn't change the color of the heading. Why does that happen?

```css
h1 {
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #0dbbeb;
}
li {
  height: 120px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: -3px 2px 1px #888888;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="N:\Desktop\Website\style.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Some Heading</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Cool Stuff</li>
      <li>Awesome Stuff</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you mean to change the color of h1?

Comment: I have changed the color of h1 with the h1 tag but i have wrapped h1 and list in the div nav and when i change the color of nav, it doesn't replace the background color of the h1, why is that?

Comment: change backgorund color of h1 if you want to change background color of h1, not #nav

Comment: @Lavios first of all hi i want to know why an extra div closed **</div>** .>?? first see this dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background-color` property is not inherited from parent elements so you have to target `h1` directly. Based on your markup if you remove `background-color` from `h1` it will show parent background but not because it's inherited but because it's a transparent layer over a colored one.

> Summary
>
> The summary of every CSS property definition says whether that
>   property is inherited by default ("Inherited: Yes") or not inherited
>   by default ("Inherited: no"). This controls what happens when no value
>   is specified for a property on an element.
>
> Inherited properties
>
> When no value for an inherited property has been specified on an
>   element, the element gets the computed value of that property on its
>   parent element. Only the root element of the document gets the initial
>   value given in the property's summary.
>
> Non-inherited properties
>
> When no value for an non-inherited property (sometimes called a reset
>   property in Mozilla code) has been specified on an element, the
>   element gets the initial value of that property (as specified in the
>   property's summary).

Reference: [MDN - background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) - [MDN - inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine CSS containers as stacked pieces of paper. Your h1 is on top of your nav so the background doesn't show, much like you will only see blue color when you put a blue paper over a green paper. The background will be shown, however, if the piece that's on top is smaller than the bottom one. If you want the background of nav to affect both containers, don't set a background for the h1 or change it to transparent.

Answer (score 2):

The background of the h1 does not change because it is specifically targeted in your h1 css rule. If you'd like the h1 to inherit the background color from #nav, you will need to remove the background rule from h1.